# memory allocation for upcasting in java

Tags: java, memory-management, upcasting

Considering these classes:

```
public class Animal{

}

public class Dog extends Animal{

}

public AnimalTest(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Dog d = new Dog();
       Animal a = d;
   }
}
```

my question is since I performed an upcasting on `Animal a = d;`does it consume a new memory allocation on the machine or does it use the memory allocated to the `Dog d = new Dog();`

Comment: `Animal a = d;` just a reference, no memory allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Animal a = d;

`a` is just a reference and the reference's memory is allocated in method stack(or jvm stack, not heap).

That is when invoke the method `main`, JVM will allocate a stack which contains the reference's space.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I would like to ask also that since Animal a is a reference and it is allocated on the stack where does Dog d allocated? on the heap?

Comment: @anathema Yes, `new Dog()` is allocated on JVM heap.

Answer (score 3):

The Actual object or its memory footprint is not affected. just a new reference to the object is created. The only difference is that the reference `a` can only call methods or access attributes that was available in the Super Class Animal.

Comment: But what happens in the heap memory?
Dog d =new Dog() creates a new Dog object in the heap and a variable d in the stack. The variable d references to the object in the heap. 
But variable a is down casted. Does that still mean it'll reference to the same object Dog object in the heap. If so how will the compiler know its downcasted.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit upcasting really helps in Runtime polymorphism/ method overriding when we have multiple child classes of a parent class. Here, instead of creating reference variables of each child class for referring to the child class object, we can have a single reference variable that is of parent class type in order to save the extra memory allocation for each reference variable in stack memory.